# Pre-2010 book: "Jaws" in a library

Tags: identification-request

I read a book a while back (probably just before 2010) that I'm trying to find again.

It's set in a somewhat surreal library, and I recall that the story line was very strongly based on Jaws, with similar characters and a shark-like creature roaming the library.  One distinguishing feature was a long series of pages that were just ASCII art of a shark approaching.  Anyone remember what book this is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

‘[The Raw Shark Texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raw_Shark_Texts)’ by Steven Hall seems to mesh with your description, the Wikipedia plot summary states:

> The plot of Jaws is referenced extensively and fully acknowledged by the characters in the book, who view it through the device of the conceptual becoming real. The climax of the novel follows the events in the film in detail, highlighting the sense of determinism and post-modern self-awareness.

The publication date is also about right, and it has this:

> Several pages form a flip book animation of a shark attack made out of text.

Edit: Thank you to user @GarethRees for adding the final clincher in comments:

> The Internet Archive has a [copy for loan](https://archive.org/details/rawsharktexts00stev), confirming that "We were on the edge of the shadowy stacks of a huge library" (p. 233) and the flip-book starting on [p. 335](https://archive.org/details/rawsharktexts00stev/page/334/mode/2up?q=library)

Comment: The Internet Archive has a [copy for loan](https://archive.org/details/rawsharktexts00stev), confirming that "We were on the edge of the shadowy stacks of a huge library" ([p. 233](https://archive.org/details/rawsharktexts00stev/page/218/mode/2up)) and the flip-book starting on [p. 335](https://archive.org/details/rawsharktexts00stev/page/334/mode/2up?q=library).